# While loop only responding to second condition

Tags: python

My while loop is only ending when it matches the second condition, the first one is being ignored, I have no idea what I am doing wrong

```
while (response !=0) or (cont != 5):
    response = os.system("ping -c 2 " + hostname)
    cont=cont+1
    print cont
    print response
```

Comment: Your loop will carry on as long as _either_ condition is satisfied. If you want it to end as soon as one condition fails, use `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: Please, use `subprocess.check_output` or a similar function to call Shell script instead of `os.system`. That way you have better control to the output. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements

Comment: The problem was using the or operator instead of and, thank you!

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I will take a look at that, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `subprocess.call`:

```
import subprocess

for count in range(5);
    response = subprocess.call(["ping", "-c", "2", hostname])
    if not response:
        break
```

Prefer an iteration with `range` or `xrange`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `or` to `and`. When it is checking the first condition and if that is false and the second condition is true, whole condition will be true. It means either first condition is true or second condition is true.

```
While ( false or true ) will be while ( true )
```

To check both the condition you should use `and`. It checks that both conditions should be `true` for the expression to be `true`.

```
while ( false and true ) will be while ( false )

while (response !=0) and (cont != 5):
    response = os.system("ping -c 2 " + hostname)
    cont=cont+1
    print cont
    print response
```